# How to write 'after a radio is being clicked on, apply this style to the other element' with SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I cannot figure out how to write this particular example with SASS:

```
input[type='radio']:checked+span { //style here }
```

I've tried this:

```
input[type='radio'] {
    &:checked {
        +span {
            //style here
        }
    }
}
```

But that does nothing. Is there another way/correct way to do it? Can someone lend me a hand? Thanks!

Comment: it works as expected on sassmeister

Comment: Hm. Then it could be something wrong with the styling I'm applying. Thanks

Comment: Is the span directly after the input, with nothing in between?

Comment: @MrLister Markup is like this: <div><input /><span class="new-checkbox"></span><label></label></div> and I'm hiding input type radio, while styling .new-checkbox. But the checked styling is not applying after I click on the radio button. Not sure what's wrong...